# Batch job in a rails app"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have one situation I don't know how to solve... I have a rails app where I store device tokens to send push notifications to iOS devices. I have a control panel where I create a query to get the devices I want to notify, but the sending process will take some while, so how can I leave a process running in background or something like that?? What's the best way of doing this?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background job, there is a great railscast on delayed_job gem check it out, also if your planning to run your app on heroku you will need a worker dyno

http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job